# How do I make multiple queries in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to make multiple query to a filter endpoint. Say the endpoint is 
`router.get('/filter', caseController.getCasesByFilteredRecord);`

I want the user to be able to make multiple queries in the frontend. Based on Sequelize documnetation, I came up with the code below. But when I tested it, it was using AND to bind all the query instead of showing result for selected query. See below my code:

**MODIFIED BASED ON @MOLDA SUGGESTION**

```
exports.getCasesByFilteredRecord = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var where = [];
        // iterate over the params
        for (let q in req.query) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[q] = { [Op.eq]: req.query[q] };
            // if q is discoveryMethod then the obj is { discoveryMethod: { [Op.eq]: req.query.discoveryMethod } }
            where.push(obj);
        }
        const filteredResult = await Case.findAll({
            attributes: { exclude: ['id', 'countryId', 'caseFullname', 'casePhone', 'createdAt', 'caseCommunityName', 'deletedAt'] },
            where: {
              [Op.or]: [
            {
             discoveryMethod: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.discoveryMethod
                  }
            },
            {
            caseAge: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.caseAge
                  }
            },
            {
            caseGender: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.caseGender
                  }
            },
            {
            caseComorbidity: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.caseComorbidity
                  }
            },
            {
            testResult: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.testResult
                  }
            },
            {
            priority: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.priority
                  }
                },
            {
            caseStatus: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.caseStatus
                        }
            },
            {
            requireBedAdmission: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.requireBedAdmidsion
                        }
            },
            {
            requireICUBed: {
                [Op.eq]: req.query.requireICUBed
                        }
            },
            {
            requireVentilator: {
              [Op.eq]: req.query.requireVentilator
                        }
            }  
                  ]
              },
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ],
            limit: 10
        });
        if (filteredResult.length === 0) {
            return res.json({
                message: 'There are no case records for this query. Please unselect some items.'
            })
        };
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            message: 'Case query records retrieved.',
            data: filteredResult
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500)
            .json({
                message: "There is an error retrieving case query records!",
                err
            });
    };
};
```

Supposed my query is like `http://localhost:8004/api/v1/cases/filter?caseComorbidity=HBP&testResult=positive&caseGender=Male`

Sequelise will Select from Case where these queries are the values entered AND join all the null values for others. But I only want it to select where I have entered the values in the query and leave out the null queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should built the `where` based on the query params you recieve.

```
exports.getCasesByFilteredRecord = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var where = [];
        // iterate over the params
        for (let q in req.query) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[q] = { [Op.eq]: req.query[q] };
            // if q is discoveryMethod then the obj is { discoveryMethod: { [Op.eq]: req.query.discoveryMethod } }
            where.push(obj);
        }
        const filteredResult = await Case.findAll({
            attributes: { exclude: ['id', 'countryId', 'caseFullname', 'casePhone', 'createdAt', 'caseCommunityName', 'deletedAt'] },
            where: {
                [Op.or]: where // assign the "where" array here
            },
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ],
            limit: 10
        });
        if (filteredResult.length === 0) {
            return res.json({
                message: 'There are no case records for this query. Please unselect some items.'
            })
        };
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            message: 'Case query records retrieved.',
            data: filteredResults
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500)
            .json({
                message: "There is an error retrieving case query records!",
                err
            });
    };
};
```

I didn't test it, so expect some mistakes ;)

**EDIT**

```
exports.getCasesByFilteredRecord = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const filteredResult = await Case.findAll({
            attributes: { exclude: ['id', 'countryId', 'caseFullname', 'casePhone', 'createdAt', 'caseCommunityName', 'deletedAt'] },
            where: req.query, // <-- req.query -> { discoveryMethod: 'blabla' } -> some.url?discoveryMethod=blabla
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ],
            limit: 10
        });
        if (filteredResult.length === 0) {
            return res.json({
                message: 'There are no case records for this query. Please unselect some items.'
            })
        };
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            message: 'Case query records retrieved.',
            data: filteredResults
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500)
            .json({
                message: "There is an error retrieving case query records!",
                err
            });
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks. I modified my code based on your suggestion but I am not getting the desire result. I want something like ```where a=1&b=2&c=3 ``` But when I query I get result where one of the conditions is met or more like the query is doing a Op.or. And in some cases even when one of the conditions is met, the query return no result.

Comment: If you want to get results that meet all params values then use `where:  req.params` intead of `where: {  [Op.or]: where }` and you don't even need to iterate over the params.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Molda